# How to start a continuation asynch without the original Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm a contractor, I've taken over a bunch of projects written by a developer who has left. One of the ASPX pages is using Tasks with a long chain of continuations to launch long processing.

When I set breakpoints in a continuation they are never hit unless I call Wait() on the Task, so I assume the Task is never being executed. I can't call Start() on a continuation and I have no access to the creation of the original Task because it occurs in a 3rd party library. How can I start the Task asynchronously?

Comment: use delegates to make a async call to the method

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, Madhu. I don't see how that's related to Tasks. I could replace most of the continuations with some other solution, but there's a chain of Tasks which comes from a library which I have to call and can't replace with anything else.

Comment: Don't you need access to the first task in order to make the first continuation?  Otherwise, how is it set in the first place "public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction)" 

"

Comment: The library returns a Task which is itself a continuation, so I can't Start that Task.

Answer (score 1):

A continuation `Task` starts only after the antecedent `Task` completes (that is the whole point of continuation). And there is no alternative way to start it, assuming you can't modify the code that creates the continuation.